# trying to find/replcace char entity using perl xml::dom::node->expandEntityRefs()

Tags: xml, perl

I'm writing a perl script to make some changes to an xml file, and one of the things I need to do is find one entity and replace another.

I want to find

```
<myelement>&#x25aa;</myelement>
```

and replace with

```
<myelement>&#x2022;</myelement>
```

I'm trying to use the XML::DOM::Node->expandEntityRefs() function, but not having any luck. I'm basically trying to do it like this:

```
# $nodeMyElement declared at top of function, not shown
my $textNode = $nodeMyElement->getFirstChild();

my $sChildText = $textNode ->toString();
# when calling from main node, the string is just nothing
my $test = $nodeMyElement ->expandEntityRefs( $sChildText );
```

# when calling from main package I get an error: Can't use string ("XML::DOM::Node") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at C:/Perl/site/lib/XML/DOM.pm line 1244.
    my $test2 = XML::DOM::Node->expandEntityRefs( $sChildText );

any ideas on what I'm doing wrong, or a better approach to this problem? 
thanks, 
bp

Comment: Had you provided a runnable demonstration, I would have played around to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I must admit I'm not the best one to answer this, and further I don't know XML::DOM. Personally I would use [Mojo::DOM](http://p3rl.org/Mojo%3a%3aDOM) but only because its what I know. Also I'm still trying to catch up on the unicode stuff. All that said here is what I came up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use v5.10;
use utf8::all;
use Mojo::DOM;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new->xml(1)->parse(<<'END');
<myelement>&#x25aa;</myelement>
END

$dom->find('myelement')
    ->grep(qr/\x{25aa}/)
    ->pluck(replace_content => "\x{2022}");

say $dom;
```

The problem is that I cannot seem to get back to the `&#x` encoding. I'm sure (?) that there must be a way to do it, or perhaps better, to force it to stay that way the whole time. Anyone?

Comment: Why must there be? Both forms are equivalent, and anything that doesn't think so is buggy.

Comment: @ikegami, perhaps you are right. Again, I'm not the guy on unicode. My own issue is that I cannot create the output as given in the OP's spec. Perhaps the answer is, this result is good enough.

Comment: I was able to match the char using this:  $sChildText = encode('us-ascii', $sChildText, Encode::FB_XMLCREF );

Comment: @badperson, you are allowed to answer your own question and accept it. In this case if you found the answer on your own, this is the right thing to do, for future readers and to mark that you no longer need help. Cheers!

Comment: @Joel: ok, still working thru the issue, and my solution was sort of problematic, but I'll probably post anyway (including a runnable example) in case it helps anyone else.